# Mongodb shell 4.0.0 not installing on Linux mint 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongo-shell

I have tried to install mongodb on linux mint18 but It was got an error 
Can you help me out 
What Do i need to do ?

Here is the below an error I have been getting in terminal

MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-30T17:30:37.317+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: i think you need to start your mongodb server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start MongoDB server first to connect through Mongo Shell, to server you need to install mongodb server in your system

If you haven't installed mongodb server you can go through [MongoDB Server Installation](http://MongoDB%20server%20Installation)

After installation make sure you have `/data/db`  directory if not run following command

```
sudo mkdir /data
sudo mkdir /data/db
sudo chmod 777 -R /data
```

Then you need to start mongodb server by,

```
sudo service mongod start
```

If it doesn't work than run following command,

```
sudo mongod
```

Now you can connect to mongodb using your mongo shell

```
mongo
```

Now you are connected!

Comment: Thanks for replaying 
but Not yet solved 
still I got some other error 

when I run mongod
then it's showing like below 
NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Comment: I got your issue i have updated my answer run new three command and again run `mongod` command and it will work

Comment: Yeah actually i got that issues same things i did first i created /data/db but if i run mongod in local it doesn't connect when I run mongod as admin then it's showing mongo in local why i don't know any way i got mongodb database

Answer (score 0):

it's sound like you have to run the mongodb server before try to connect:

bin/mongod is the server executable

bin/mongo is the client shell interface

Comment: First what happened I have installed mongodb in my system 
Then I ran this command 
Mongo
it was showing an error 
NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

I created a path before that I did run mongodb start